# How to test in JEST a request that downloads a file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I want to unit test the exported method in the code below. Trying to write unit tests for a function that is downloading a zip file from a `localhost` server.I will write my function bellow so you understand better:

```
export const downloadCdn = async (cdnUrl, out) => {
  const download = (resolve, reject) => {
    const req = request({
      method: 'GET',
      uri: cdnUrl
    });

    req.on('response', (data) => {
      // do something
    });

    req.on('error', (data) => {
      // do something
    });

    req.on('data', (chunk) => {
      // do something
    });

    req.on('end', () => {
      console.log('download done');
    });

    req.pipe(out);
    out.on('close', () => {
      resolve([null, 'done']);
    });
  };
  const downloadSummary = new Promise(download);
  return downloadSummary
    .then(() => [null, 'Done'])
    .catch(err => [err, null]);
};
```

Here are my test file, what I'm trying to achieve is to have unit test that validates the download of the zip file:

```
import request from 'request';
import * as Module from './downloadCdn';

jest.mock('request', () => {
  const mockRequest = {
    pipe: jest.fn(),
    on: jest.fn(),
  };
  return function () {
    return mockRequest;
  };
});

describe('Downloading a file', () => {
  it('Should find the module', () => {
    expect(typeof Module.downloadCdn === 'function').toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('Should download the zip', async () => {
    const [error, response] = await Module.downloadCdn(cdnUrl, out);
    expect(response === 'Done').toBeTruthy();
    expect(error === null).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

The `response` from the `Promise`, I receive inside the test is `null`, no `error` catching. Here is the error received from jest:

```
expect(received).toBeTruthy()

Expected value to be truthy, instead received false
```

Comment: you will need to mock the request method, and trigger all the event listeners inside the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While mocking the request, you should resolve the promise. I think that promise is not resolving that's why it's not working. I hope that the below code will be fixed your problem.

```
jest.mock('request', () => {
  const mockRequest = {
    pipe: jest.fn(),
    on: (parameter, callback) => {
       callback();
    },
  };
  return function () {
    return mockRequest;
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped indeed